# Zend Server phpmyadmin not found

Tags: phpmyadmin, zend-server

I have downloaded Zend server and am using port 8000 instead of localhost, I have deployed phpmyadmin and am trying to access it via the following url:

```
http://localhost:8000/phpMyAdmin
```

However this does work, under Zend Server -> Applications -> Apps the base url is set to localhost:8000

Any ideas!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the webserver error log.

Check the case of the folder/alias you've created (the URL may be case sensitive; if the folder on disk is `phpmyadmin` then also try `http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin`). Check folder and file permissions on the phpMyAdmin directory. Try `http://locahost:8000/`.

As a side note, you aren't using port 8000 "instead of localhost" as localhost is the hostname of the machine and 8000 is the port number. So you're using 8000 instead of port 80, which is the most common port for web page access. You're still accessing it on the localhost machine.

Comment: I think another issue I am experiencing might be causing this issue.